# RxJava Backpressure Buffer when Necessary

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, reactivex

I'm trying to get a specific desired behavior with RxJava, and I can't figure out how to do it.

I want variable length buffer BackPressureStrategy.

I.E. my subscriber get's sent all the elements as they come individually when there is no backpressure.  When there is back pressure, I want to get all of the new elements (as a list) that were published in between the last time my consumer was called and now.

Is this possible>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `buffer()` operator to create a list of items. Variations of the operator allow you to set the maximum size or the maximum period of time over which to collect items, or to use a second observable to trigger end-of-buffer.

As an extreme example, you can create a flow-control observable that controls the buffer. For instance, using the `debounce()` operator to control when the buffer is emitted. Read through the [RxJava examples](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html)

Comment: I've read through the RxJava examples, here is why the default buffer() and debounce() operations don't work for me:

1. buffer().  I want my function to get called as soon as possible.  I can do this by having a really short buffer max duration.  If do that, the buffer doesn't actually help me beacause (if I get backed up) I'll have lots of pending buffers, not one single large buffer.

2. debounce().  This filters out rapid events.  I need to capture all events.

Comment: In the example code, for using the `buffer()` operator with `debounce()` as a trigger, the `debounce()` operator does not filter out the individual events. Instead, `debounce()` will fire when the first event in an interval arrives, causing the `buffer()` operator to emit immediately. If more events arrive during the debounce interval, `debounce()` won't fire, allowing `buffer()` to accumulate items.